# How do I retrieve the values for a multiselect in angular foms?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-formbuilder

I am having an issue retrieving the selected value of a multiple select control in my angular form. Basically I am getting the array position rather than the actual id value.

Here is my control

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let asset of (assetList | async)" [value]="asset.assetId">{{asset.assetName}}</mat-option>
```

And the form initialisation

```
profileForm=this.fb.group({
    assets:[],
    capacity:[],
  });
```

Here is my code to retrieve the value

```
for(var asset in this.profileForm.controls["assets"].value){
      let assetItem=new Asset();
      assetItem.AssetId=Number(asset);
      assetList.push(assetItem);
    }
```

Here are the values in the form(from the chrome console) when I do console.log(this.profileForm.controls["assets"].value)

```
> value: Array(3) 
0: 1 
1: 2 
2: 3 
length: 3
```

So basically I am getting the value 0 instead of 1 and 1 instead of 2 etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you change [value] to [ngValue] and check?

Comment: changing it to ngValue causes an error as it is not a valid property on a mat-option

Comment: If you select random items in the dropdown, let's say 1st and 3rd item. What is the output?

Comment: Exactly the same (ie I get the array position not the value) Eg 0:2 1:4 2:6

Comment: Yes this is because map-options is returning the output in array format with index starting from 0. But the ID of the element you select is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found what I was doing wrong...

If I change

```
for(var asset in this.profileForm.controls["assets"].value){
      let assetItem=new Asset();
      assetItem.AssetId=Number(asset);
      assetList.push(assetItem);
    }
```

to

```
for(var asset of this.profileForm.controls["assets"].value){
      let assetItem=new Asset();
      assetItem.AssetId=Number(asset);
      assetList.push(assetItem);
    }
```

It gets the correct values. Basically For...in returns the keys for the object being iterated while For...of returns the values of the object being iterated.